# Linux grep command to find the value of key from json

Tags: json, linux, shell, curl, grep

I have a JSON output that contains a list of objects stored in a variable.(I may not be phrasing that right)

Output of a curl command: will post in comment as I am unable to post here

I want to grep the value at this position "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58" shown in the output, which changes everytime i run the curl command. I want that to pass as a input to other curl command.

Please help

Comment: ` {  
   "destination":[  
      {  
         "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58":{  
            "throttle_bytes_per_second":"0",
            "delete_this":false,
            "path":"s3testbucket",
            "server_side_encryption":false,
            "provider":"s3",
            "access_key":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "access_secret":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         }
      }
   ],
   "request_id":"d6e089bb-9729-423b-8319-d441e0a72202"
    
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"jq" https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ is necessary for this. If for "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58", itself is changed every time, how about following script?

```
of="data.json" && curl ..... -o $of > $of && key=$(cat $of | jq -r '.destination[0]|keys' | jq -r '.[]') && jq -r ".destination[0].$key" $of && unset key of
```

- Data got by curl is output as name of "$of".
- Position of "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58" is retrieved as "$key".
- Value of "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58" is output using "$key".

For example, in this script, when the position of "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58" is not changed, "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58" can be changed to "abcdefg1234567".

Answer (score 0):

Use `jq`:

`curl 'http://.../some.json' | jq .destination[0].ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58`

Answer (score 0):

like this?:

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
import sys
import json
aa = '''{
    "destination": [
        {
            "ad6743fae9c54748b8644564c691ba58": {
                "throttle_bytes_per_second": "0",
                "delete_this": false,
                "path": "s3testbucket",
                "server_side_encryption": false,
                "provider": "s3",
                "access_key": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                "access_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            }
        }
    ],
    "request_id": "d6e089bb-9729-423b-8319-d441e0a72202"
}'''

# aa=sys.argv[1]

bb = json.loads(aa)
print bb["request_id"]
```